# I applied R "particle" package to ocean velocity data and got an error saying I was out of memory

Tags: r, velocity, particles, ocean

I am trying to apply an example from R "particles" package to ocean velocity data (kinetic energy).
Example data is as follows:

```
ke1<-c(0.394610137,0.203202814,0.12364389,0.069784589,0.048573241,0.043057494,0.03826768,0.034176417,0.032129359,0.03122394)
ke2<-c(0.094138406,0.169889584,0.086677499,0.070593894,0.049883354,0.042339094,0.038856283,0.037967827,0.036562074,0.037240546)
ke3<-c(0.054365572,0.096576959,0.10304369,0.061354585,0.053624138,0.042112421,0.040727202,0.039870735,0.042947762,0.043291345)
ke4<-c(0.030527802,0.075901449,0.08003746,0.068991989,0.048506431,0.044592839,0.04071483,0.042985249,0.042403288,0.044974718)
ke5<-c(0.021374704,0.047852065,0.070487022,0.059393879,0.051129311,0.042866949,0.040003292,0.040003441,0.044107087,0.04578279)
ke<-cbind(ke1,ke2,ke3,ke4,ke5)

library(particles)
library(tidygraph)
    

sim <- create_empty(1000) %>% 
  simulate(alpha_decay = 0, setup = aquarium_genesis(vel_max = 1)) %>%
  wield(reset_force, xvel = 0, yvel = 0) %>% 
  wield(field_force, angle = ke, vel = ke , xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-5, 5)) %>% 
      evolve(1000, record)
```

Increasing the amount of velocity data(row = 233, col = 154), the following error occurred.

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 152.6 Mb
```

I tried to check the amount of memory I used with gc().

```
 gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   2765657   84.5    4718054  144.0   4718054  144.0
Vcells 311435640 2376.1  480298947 3664.4 439560179 3353.6
```

memory.limit is 4000(uplimit).
Could I say it was caused by the PC memory?

Comment: It is because you do not have enough RAM. I _think_  you likely have more objects (e.g., variables) in your environment that you could try to remove. I tried simulating 233 rows and 154 columns and allocated 709.2 MB for `sim` within a clean session. So the first step is cleaning your environment or starting a new, fresh session.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I ran "sim" within a clean session you recommended.  "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 76.3 Mb" was shown after plot() function.

Comment: Yeah, still not enough RAM. If you only have 4 GB of RAM, you may want to look into upgrading - my machine has 16GB. Alternatively, you could be more active in cleaning your environment. For example, if you are done with the `ke` matrix, remove it. You can also export to .csv if you still need it.